# Dependencies in installing ursina engine

Tags: python-3.x, ursina, panda3d

I can't install ursina engine. I got a error like this:

"ERROR: Cannot install ursina==0.2, ursina==0.3, ursina==3.0.0, ursina==3.1.0, ursina==3.1.1, ursina==3.1.2, ursina==3.2.2, ursina==3.3.0, ursina==3.3.1, ursina==3.4.0, ursina==3.5.0, ursina==3.6.0, ursina==4.0.0, ursina==4.1.0, ursina==4.1.1, ursina==5.0.0, ursina==5.1.0, ursina==5.2.0, ursina==5.3.0, ursina==6.0.0, ursina==6.1.0, ursina==6.1.1 and ursina==6.1.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
ursina 6.1.2 depends on panda3d
ursina 6.1.1 depends on panda3d
ursina 6.1.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 6.0.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 5.3.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 5.2.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 5.1.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 5.0.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 4.1.1 depends on panda3d
ursina 4.1.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 4.0.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.6.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.5.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.4.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.3.1 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.3.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.2.2 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.1.2 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.1.1 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.1.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 3.0.0 depends on panda3d
ursina 0.3 depends on panda3d
ursina 0.2 depends on panda3d

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

Possible solutions listed on the pip site does not cover my case. Furthermore, problem iwth running ursina on my computer occurs also with build-in packages IDE like Mu Editor.

I tried several IDE with build-in Packages and installing ursina through the terminal in some IDEs like VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install ursina "per hand". So install

`https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/archive/master.zip` in your browser, then

move the ursina engine folder to your site-packages and execute the following commands:

```
pip install jurigged
pip install -U --pre --extra-index-url https://archive.panda3d.org/ panda3d.
```

This is fixing the bug. But it's because the newest panda3d is not for python 3.12.

Of course, you also have to install the other libraries, necessary for ursina engine like screeninfo, gltf, pyperclip

optional psd-tools3 and tripy

and you have to change ursina's code in ursina/entity.py

```
def blink(self, value=ursina.color.clear, duration=.1, delay=0, curve=curve.in_expo_boomerang, interrupt='finish', unscaled=False, **kwargs):
        return self.animate_color(value, duration=duration, delay=delay, curve=curve, interrupt=interrupt, unscaled=unscaled, **kwargs)`
```

to

```
def blink(self, value=color.clear, duration=.1, delay=0, curve=curve.in_expo_boomerang, interrupt='finish', unscaled=False, **kwargs):
    return self.animate_color(value, duration=duration, delay=delay, curve=curve, interrupt=interrupt, unscaled=unscaled, **kwargs)
```

Comment: panda3d 1.10.14 is out now! so it wont be a problem anymore

Answer (score 1):

try it in python 3.10 because its not supported in new versions
i had the same problem with python 3.12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).